# The functionality of @Service annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, service, spring-messaging

This is a kind of "what is @Service annotation?" question, but with another approach. Because, I am not sure what is going on here:

I have a controller class:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @Autowired
    SomeBean someBean;

    @MessageMapping("/msg")
    public String msg() {
        someBean.handleMsg();
        return "";
    }
}
```

From within `someBean.handleMsg` I try to send a response to a destination.
Some thing like this:

```
public class SomeBean {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    public handleMsg() {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/someTopic", "Response");
    }
}
```

There are **two versions of configuration**.

1. SomeBean is configured in **.xml**:

Like:

```
< bean id="someBean" class="package.SomeBean"></bean>
```

2. SomeBean is annotated as **service** (in the first one it does not have):

Like:

```
@Service
public class SomeBean{...}
```

- Please note that in these two cases there is not any problem about injections etc. In both cases the client is successfully subscribed, sent message, and message is handled.

The **only** **difference** is:

- When `SomeBean` has `@Service` annotation, it successfully responses to the client, but when it does **NOT** have, the client does not receive the response message, although there is not any exception.

Here is the question:

- What actually does @Service in this case? Could someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: Doesn't the file service.java of package org.springframework.stereotype indicate why service annotations are for? I see that it does.

Comment: I have trouble believing your description of events; failure to send the message, for a number of reasons, would generate a corresponding exception. Something else is different. You might consider setting a breakpoint in the service method and stepping through in each case.

Comment: @chrylis, maybe you're right, I also wonder why I didn't get any exception but just silently the client receives nothing when there is not Service annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a technical point of view there is little difference between `@Service` and xml based configuration. Both methods are used for declaring Java classes as Spring beans which are managed and used for dependency injection inside a Spring based application.

Main difference is that a class annotated with `@Service` is a candicate for autodetection during classpath scanning. With annotation driven dependency injection you don't need to declare every Java class as a Spring bean inside your xml configuration.

That is what the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) says:

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "Service", originally defined
>   by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "an operation offered as an
>   interface that stands alone in the model, with no encapsulated state."
>
> May also indicate that a class is a "Business Service Facade" (in the
>   Core J2EE patterns sense), or something similar. This annotation is a
>   general-purpose stereotype and individual teams may narrow their
>   semantics and use as appropriate.
>
> This annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for
>   implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

Comment: Thank you ksokol. So could you tell that in my question the behaviour in 2 cases should be the same? I do have read this javadoc but I couldn't explain my case, so I though I was missing some thing.

Comment: @mert-mertce Yes you're right. The behaviour is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

**@Service**: This tells Spring it is a Service class, where you might have `@Transactional` etc Service layer related annotations so Spring treats it as a Service component.

Plus `@Service` is a specialization of `@Component`. Assume the bean class name is "CustomerService", since you did not choose XML bean configuration way so you annotated the bean with `@Component` to indicate it as a Bean. So you can retrieve this bean with :

```
CustomerService cust = (CustomerService)context.getBean("customerService");
```

By default, Spring will lower case the first character of the component – from ‘CustomerService’ to ‘customerService’. And you can retrieve this component with name ‘customerService’.

Just like with the `@Component` annotation, if you use the `@Service` annotation you can provide it a specific bean name like this :

```
@Service("myBeanName")
public class CustomerService{
```

and you can get the bean object by :

```
CustomerService cust = (CustomerService)context.getBean("myBeanName");
```